# How to save content/text of a web page by forcing save-as option

Tags: php, javascript, html, save

I would like to know what would be the best way to save contents from a web page. I mean to force save-as option by clicking a link or button. I often found that javascript would not be an option because it's only working for IE, so I thought that it would be easier because javascript is client-side based.

Now, I thought maybe there is a way to use php when creating a form that will redirect it over a server site query to return and force the save-as option. My main goal is make it possible to save the privacy terms. I would like to avoid using fpdf. If there is someone who could tell how to solve this I would really appreciate it.

UPDATE:

okay to explain what i like to reach:

imagine you have a simple webpage with some privacy policy text and nothing else. at the top of the page you have two options. first will be print option like:

```
<a href="javascript:print()">print</a>
```

second should be something like:

```
<a href="javascript:saveas()">save</a>
```

so that when you will press the link the save-as dialog pops up and you can download the content or even page to get the privacy policy for your own.

hope it will be clear now. sorry.

Comment: Would the pages you want to save be hosted by yourself?

Comment: hello, not at the moment. maybe one day but at the moment there is nothing beeing planned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to force a download without javascript, simply open the content in a new tab by adding an unknown target.

**Example Code**

```
<a href="whatever.com/download.zip" target="_new">click me</a>
```

This works only if the page you call offers a download, otherwise the content gets displayed. In this case, you need a simple php-file, which gets the content from the page and customizes the header.

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents($_GET["downloadurl"]);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
echo $content;
?>
```

---

**UPDATE**

As a more detailed example for your edited informations, you could probably do this:

**PHP-File** "reader.php"

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents($_GET["downloadurl"]);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
echo $content;
?>
```

**HTML** on page "test.html"

```
<a href="reader.php?downloadurl=http://yourwebsite.com/test.html" target="_new">Save website</a>
```

Comment: What's `file_get_source()` ?

Comment: I think what's more important is using `Content-Disposition`, but I'm sure this still works

Comment: Sorry, meant to say `file_get_contents`.

Comment: hello, i think this is not working the right way. i tried that but now the savas dialog will be opened when loading the page?! this is not what i wanted. i would like to have it to save a button/linked text on its same page to download its content from the same page. thanks.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you're aiming to get, i'm sorry. Please explain your problem further more. Do you want to start a download when clicking on a link?!

Comment: hello, i updated my question to give further information. thanks.

Comment: That clears it up, even though i don't know whats the problem with my method, it's able to do exactly what you want to do. Use the file_get_contents-method and let it point to the page the user is currently on. This way the user is able to download the pages content. Did it become clear or should i make a little bit more detailed example?

Comment: hello, okay i tried to comprehend the php script. file_get_contents returns the content of the page through a string and uses GET to get the url path as a source. so that`s clear. the problem will be the "a href.." that i dont understand at the moment. the text is linked to a href page that does not exist and will be opened in a new window? thanks.

Comment: See my edit for more informations and remember to upvote useful posts and mark them as solving if it did for you.