# Javascript or Jquery that will enabe me to add "Save This Page As" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to enable users to save the html page they are visiting in a better way than forcing them to use File > Save As.

I would like to add a button somewhere in the page that says "Save Page As", and when the user clicks on it, it will open the save as dialog.

Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save content/text of a web page by forcing save-as option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758968/how-to-save-content-text-of-a-web-page-by-forcing-save-as-option)

Comment: Works in IE. And only IE afaik.

Answer (score 0):

can you please used this for IE only

```
document.execCommand('SaveAs',true,'file.html');
```

And other browser Not precisely, but you can do it by hyperlinking to the img file and setting the content-type and content-disposition headers in the server response. Try, e.g., application/x-download [plus the other headers specified here](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jebp_3/index3.html)