# Force "Save As" or "Save Link As" with PHP header

Tags: php, header, download, mp3

I'm trying to force a Save As dialog. However, the caveat is that I'm trying to use a bit.ly to track statistics on the downloads. This is how I'm *trying* to achieve this effect.

My .html file:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="51,1004,303,1263" href="mp3_download?downloadurl=http://bit.ly/1byeeR7" id="cult_download" />
```

and my php file:

```
<?php 
$content = file_get_contents($_GET["downloadurl"]);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;"); 
?>
```

This is using what I've seen on [How to save content/text of a web page by forcing save-as option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758968/how-to-save-content-text-of-a-web-page-by-forcing-save-as-option). But, it's not working as expected.

Suggestion on better ways to track the statistics of the downloads welcome, too!
Thanks!

Comment: Does href="mp3_download?downloadurl=http://bit.ly/1byeeR7" offers download?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can track the downloads via Google Analytics: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#Labels
2. If you want to continue using PHP for tracking downloads, you need to secure the input - please be aware, that anything can be passed to downloadurl (e.g. path to some private local files) and you would serve them to end user
3. If you still want to pass data through php (try to download some big files this way - you will probably run out of the `memory_limit`), you can use [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile), which reads the input and passes it to the output without memory problems (there is a good example how to do the download in [the docs](http://php.net/readfile)